# Git merge issues unrelated branche histories

Tags: git, git-merge

I have converted a repository from svn to git which had a customised structure in svn and I have to extract branches from the trunk's directory structure. Migrated git branches are:

```
branch: origin/branch_0.1.0
    contents: file_A
    change: created file_A

branch: origin/branch_0.2.0
    contents: file_B
    change: removed file_A, created file_B

branch: origin/branch_0.3.0
    contents: file_B
    change: edited file_B
```

here you can note that I do not have a `master` branch which I create in post process by merging all the above extracted branches in order with merge command as `git merge -X theirs --allow-unrelated-histories origin/<branch>` and if there are unmerged files then additionally run `git add -A && git commit -m "<msg>"`. Issue I have is that the final `master` branch end up having both files `file_A` and `file_B` but the expected result should be only `file_B` as it was the only file present in last merged branch(`branch_0.3.0`).

I have also tried removing all the files (`git rm -r .`) before I do the procedural merge of branches but then I encounter an issue where `file_B` does not exists (while performing the merge for `branch_0.3.0`) but edited in HEAD/ other branches.

Could some one give me some pointers to fix this issue and also let me know if more information is required.

Cheers,
DD.

Comment: What `--allow-unrelated-histories` does is treat a merge that has no merge base commit as having the [empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452) as its merge base. This just means that all files in both of the to-be-merged commits are new. See other SO postings where I explain how `git merge` normally works.

Comment: Can you post a view of the history of your commits ? `git log --graph --oneline origin/branch_0.1.0 origin/branch_0.2.0 origin/branch_0.3.0`

Answer (score 0):

If the three branches you created are one behind the other, e.g :

- if `origin/branch_0.2.0` is based on `origin/branch_0.1.0`
- and `origin/branch_0.3.0` is based on `origin/branch_0.3.0`

the starting point for your `master` branch is simply `origin/branch_0.3.0` :

```
git branch master origin/branch_0.3.0
git checkout master
```